# Guava cache not caching

Tags: java, caching, guava, in-memory

I am new to caching with Google Guava but having some issues. Please look at below code it is simple. Following are my questions and code. 1. Whenever I call method `testGuavaCache("6048698068");` from another class - it ALWAYS EVERY TIME RUN METHOD - `generateDataFromDAO();`. Should not this method be called ONLY once as first time it will cache when its not present in the memory and next time it will serve from the memory. Appreciate your early reply.

```
public class GuavaCach{
    private static Logger objLogger = Logger.getLogger(WordToPDF.class);    
    LoadingCache<String, String> guavaCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(10000)
        .build(
            new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
            public String load(String key) throws Exception {   
                objLogger.debug("-----KEY IN LOAD BEFORE calling generateDataFromDAO------->" + key + "<-------");
                String out =  generateDataFromDAO();
                objLogger.debug("-----out after calling generateDataFromDAO------->" + out + "<-------");
                return out;
            }
    });

    public String testGuavaCache(String key) throws IOException {
        String dataFromDAO = null;
        objLogger.debug("-----Entering testGuavaCache-----");
        try {
            dataFromDAO = guavaCache.get(key);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataFromDAO; 
    }         

    public String generateDataFromDAO() throws PreviewErrorMsg, IOException {
        objLogger.debug("-----Entering generateDataFromDAO-----");
        String data = "GeneratedDataFromDAO";       
        return data;
    }
}
```

In another class - I am calling above :

GuavaCach gCache = new GuavaCach(); gCache..testGuavaCache("6048698068");

Comment: You aren't showing the code that's calling these methods or the output. There may be some difference in the two calls that would explain the issue.

Comment: GuavaCach gCache = new GuavaCach();  gCache..testGuavaCache("6048698068");

Comment: Are you calling `new GuavaCach()` every time?

Comment: Yes - calling new GuavaCach() every time

Answer (score 5):

You're creating an entire new cache every time you ask a question, and the (empty) new cache doesn't have any answers in it. You need to create one cache, keep it around, and ask it the same question over and over to get the benefits. You didn't post much of how you're using it, but you should only call `new GuavaCach()` in your other code, and then call `g.testGuavaCache(key)` repeatedly.

Comment: Or change the private `guavaCache` member to be static.